# Wildcard Django Logging

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to wildcard a package when setting up Django logs?

Right now my `LOGGING` looks like:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'mypack.mod1': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'mypack.mod2': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

and my question is, is there some way to avoid needing a section for both `mypack.mod1` and `mypack.mod2`.

Answer (score 11):

yes, there is a way (well several even). The simplest (and probably the best also) way is to define your logger this way:

```
    'mypack': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
```

When in `mypack.mod2` you are calling `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`, name is actually `mypack.mod2`. Using the dotted notation if python can't find a logger for `mypack.mod2`, it will try for its parent (and do on if you have several layers like `mypack.mod1.submod3.subsubmod42`) and wil be catched by the logger named `mypack`.

An other way (although I wouldn't recommend it except if you really know what you are doing) is to explicitly call a specific logger by name by using `logger = logging.getLogger('TheNameOfTheLoggerIWantToCall')` instead of the usual call with `__name__`

You can also take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/#naming-loggers for more information.

[Updated]
Under the same principle of "parental hierarchy", a logger named with an empty string would catch everything (not just Django, every log from every python module in use)

Comment: Is there some way to make a full wild card logger that will catch everything logged by any logger?

Comment: @AlexRothberg the root logger (i.e. loggng.getLogger()) will catch everything (usually).